# Hibernate one-to-many association saves duplicates

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a class `A` that can have an association to multiple `B`s (one-to-many):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 6796905221158242611L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name = "a_id")
 private Long a_id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Set<B> bs;

 public void addB(B b) {
  if(bs == null)
   bs = new HashSet<B>();

  bs.add(b);
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
}
```

and class `B` storing a reference to `A`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 6063558165223241323L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name = "b_id")
 private Long b_id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
 private A a;

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public A getA() {
  return a;
 }

 public void setA(A a) {
  this.a = a;
 }
}
```

When I now execute the following code Hibernate will save two entries in tables `b` both having the name `b1`. I do not know how to avoid this or what I am doing wrong.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Configurations.MYSQL);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

em.getTransaction().begin();

A a1 = new A();
a1.setName("a1");

A a2 = new A();
a2.setName("a2");

B b = new B();
b.setName("b1");

a1.addB(b);
a2.addB(b);

em.merge(a1);
em.merge(a2);

em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Merge A1 and A2, then B and afterwards add B to the As. That should actually work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be saving a1 and a2 instead of merging them. From the javadocs, this is what merge does.

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the
>   same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently
>   associated with the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent
>   instance. If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return
>   it as a newly persistent instance. The given instance does not become
>   associated with the session. This operation cascades to associated
>   instances if the association is mapped with cascade="merge".

So, since you are cascading merge you are merging b. But b is unsaved, so a copy of b will be saved. So merging a1 will save a copy of b, and merging a2 will save another copy of b.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by inventing a mapping table between A and B (which then has two entries by itself), because every B stores the reference to its A in a column and as the first normal form of databases state, you only have atomic values and so no single B line with two primary keys of A in one column.